# Use DASH to display two dataframes on one page

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I would like to create a second dataframe and then display two tables on a page.  Right now this displays just one.  It looks like dash_bootstrap_components would allow me to segment the screen, but I can't find examples with more than one table

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

#would like to add a second dataframe here
df1 = pd.read_sas('C:\PY_DASH\file1.sas7bdat', format = 'sas7bdat', encoding='utf-8' )

def generate_table(dataframe, max_rows=7):
    return html.Table(
        # Header
        [html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in dataframe.columns])] +

        # Body
        [html.Tr([
            html.Td(dataframe.iloc[i][col]) for col in dataframe.columns
        ]) for i in range(min(len(dataframe), max_rows))]
    )

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

#I would like to add the second table here
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='QA Test: Test 0-1: Output Files Record Count Comparison'),
    generate_table(df1)
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to separate out the chunk of code that generates each table. Then assemble them both inside a dcc container, which can then be used in your layout. This makes it easy to debug also later :). Below is some sample code to give you an idea of what I mean.

First the section to generate table 1. Within this you may use your function `generate_table`

```
one_row = html.Tr([html.Td(<content>, id="row1" )])
t_head = [
      html.Thead(html.Tr([html.Th("Table1")]))
]
table1_section = dbc.Card(children=[
    dbc.CardHeader(html.H5("Table1 header", id="t_head")),
    dbc.CardBody([
      dbc.Table(t_head + [html.Tbody([one_row])])
    ])
])
```

Similarly make `table2_section`
Next assemble this as a `dbc.Row()` if required.

Finally, put them all together in a `dbc.Container` eg:

```
page_content = dbc.Container([
      table1_section,
      table2_section,
      somegraph_section
], fluid=True)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try that.  I finally took a udemy python course and a plotless dash dashboard course.  I’m getting a clearer picture of how it works now.

Comment: *plotly not plotless